# Getting different Base64 String when trying to convert through Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString java

Tags: java, javascript, image, base64, arrays

I Uploaded one file Tried converting the image to Base64 String through this site http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/. When i am copying the base64 string from this site then it is working in my code and  image is getting displayed properly
But, when i am trying to convert the image into Base64 String  through Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString the Base64 String which i am getting is not working in my code and image is not getting displayed.

Further i analysed i found out that difference between Base64 String which i copied from site and which i am generated through encodeBase64URLSafeString. Attached the snapshot for reference.Also attached the code for reference.

```
    //this line will fetch the image data from db and i am storing into byte array
     byte[] imageData = smpResource.getValue();

    //i am adding this byte array into json object and sending.
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    result.put("image", imageData);

     selectedImage.innerHTML = "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64, temp'/>";
```

Seems like some character encoding problem.Right side of the image is working one copied from site .Can see the diff / replaced with _.How to overcome this problem.Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: The '/' is a special character in the URL, the 'path separator', and so not a part of the 'URL safe' alphabet. You probably just need to use the basic or mime encoder.

Comment: @zanerock--Problem solved i am using now encodeBase64String instead of encodeBase64URLSafeString . Thanks